# How to set mongo db dbpath on windows 7?

Tags: mongodb

How do I set mongo db dbpath on windows 7? I created a directory in my my C drive as data/db but it is not working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The mongodb data dir is not application specific. It is `mongod.exe` process specific.

As [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows#QuickstartWindows-Createadatadirectory) says

> By default MongoDB will store data in \data\db, but it won't
>   automatically create that folder, so we do so here:
>
> ```
> C:\> mkdir \data
> C:\> mkdir \data\db Or you can do this from the Windows Explorer, of course.
> ```
>
> If you prefer to place datafiles elsewhere, use the --dbpath command
>   line parameter when starting mongod.exe.

This means that you need to create `C:\data\db` directory or start `mongod.exe` with the full path to your data dir as `--dbpath` parameter value.

Comment: I am new to mongo and trying to also install for the first time. I am still getting error after creating that folder.

Comment: @user52045 it is possible to configure windows service https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb and use a config file with all the settings you need.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally add

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin;
```

to your Path variable.

Answer (score 1):

-->   in the path of windows paste url install  for example: C:/mongodb/bin
-->here mongod.exe and mongo.exe

add C:/mongodb/bin

open cmd, write:
mongod
open other cmd,write
mongo

enjoy :)

PD: It's the same for other python, ruby etc. Windows is hurts T_T haha