# Cannot run mongo/mongod with Git Bash but it runs in the Git CMD (mongo: not found)

Tags: node.js, git, bash, mongodb, path

So today I tried to get going with MongoDB on my computer but run into troubles right from the start.

After I installed mongo on my machine, It tried to run "mongod" and "mongo" in Git Bash but with no luck. The error I get is "mongod: not found"/"mongo: not found" respectively.

Now I saw in some answers here people recommending to change the enviromental variable PATH on my machine to the path to the mongod/mongo full path.

But the problem is that on my machine this variable is already set to the path of my npm (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm).

Will changing the path variable help me here or will it cause issues with npm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is that on my machine this variable is already set to
>   the path of my npm

The `PATH` environment variable is a delimited set of paths, not just one path. On windows it is delimited by a semi-colon "`;`".

So, append the path to mongo to your PATH environment variable.

[Here are some instructions for setting environment variables](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531893/how-to-set-mongo-db-dbpath-on-windows-7) is a related question regarding setting `PATH` for Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I would recommend setting the PATH variable of mongodb to its bin folder in the installation path. So it would be, per example, `D:\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin`, add that to your path variable and it should work. You shouldn't have any npm issues.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *replace* `PATH`, you want to *append* to it: `PATH` is actually a list of paths. In windows this is semi-colon delimited: `set PATH=%PATH%;/path/to/mongo` and *nix (which Git Bash should mimic) it's colon delimited: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/mongo`.

Answer (score -2):

I use mongodb with git bash in windows. Install normaly, set the directory in c:/mongodb --> automaticaly set bin, mongo.exe, mongod.exe and all de files.
Create in c:/data/db   --> console with mkdir data/db  or in windows area

```
Open your git bash :  
cd .. 
--> cd.. 
--> cd c:/mongodb/bin/ 
--> ls
in this console 
./mongod
```

> in other console open

```
--> cd .. 
--> cd.. 
--> cd c:/mongodb/bin/  
--> ls
./mongo
```

(before version git bash only mongod and mongo , In this case is ./mongod and ./mongo)

PD: I sorry for my english :p