# mongodb windows10 connection failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection, mean-stack

I have installed mongodb and did proper R&D to run it like create folder like C:\data and setting path in environment variable for mongodb.

Whenever i am trying to connect with mongodb i got below error:

[mongo command error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AOVM.png)

[mongod command error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76wQZ.png)

Could not able to run mongo command in shell because of connection problem.

Already tried hacks:

[Reference link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726684/mongodb-on-a-windows-7-machine-no-connection-could-be-made)

[Reference link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629917/mongodb-get-error-as-an-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

[Reference link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404742/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows)

[Reference link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531893/how-to-set-mongo-db-dbpath-on-windows-7)

Looking for current scenario help.

Please suggest any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a firewall?

Comment: @lud1977 no firewall have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Create another folder inside C:\data called db. It should work fine now.

Comment: Open cmd with 'Run as administrator' and then try again.